# How to apply InStr to match header name with array of names?

Tags: excel, vba

My macro is supposed to match header name with array of names.

- if true, omit it
- if not, set value from second row to the last row as Customer

Initially, I had the customer value on the "Else" part but the macro did the other way around as supposed - only changed cells on array values. It doesn't make sense to me, as I've though that I've set my InStr function to positive output however I've put the instruction on match part

Out of 70 variables, did 67 positively as intended, 3 variables were named Customer and in few of them it doesn't went from 2nd to last, but for instance only second, or only few of them.

```vb
Sub test2()
    
    Dim HeaderRow As Range
    Dim HeaderName As String
    
    HeaderName = Join(Array("ID", "GENDER", "REVENUE"))

    Set HeaderRow = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight))
    
    For Each Header In HeaderRow
    
        Debug.Print Header
        Debug.Print HeaderName
        If InStr(1, HeaderName, Header.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Range(Cells(2, Header.Column).Address, Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, Header.Column).End(xlUp).Row, Header.Column).Address).Value2 = "Customer"
        Else
                
        End If
        
    Next Header
    
End Sub
```

For example that column BD is what it is supposed to be, all these columns have gaps but BD, BF, BG, BO are good (1-59 rows on that particular file, rest are not).

Plus something mentioned earlier - sometimes header is set to customer and first row, nothing else.
[image: wrong fill]

New HeaderRow gives me mismatch, when i change to ws.Range initially it gets only first column, like that is not drag xlToLeft
[image: wrong header]

Comment: This `InStr(1, HeaderName, Header.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0` means it did NOT match. `Instr` returns the **position** where the string was found, if it returns `0` that means the string was NOT found. So your code reads like *"`If` string not found `Then` replace data `Else` do nothing `End If`"*. • For me the code works perfect, no issues.

Comment: Thank you. I've modified it a little and it get consistency! However, any idea how to loop it over all worksheets as my standard solution does not work? I've set ws as worksheets and then above For each Header I've got For Each ws in Thisworkbook.Worksheets and later in the end after Next Header i got Next ws, but it doen't go through all of WS, just one active

Comment: You need to reference your ranges and cells with the worksheet `ws`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through all worksheets `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` and make sure all `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` and `Colums` objects are referenced with the worksheet like `ws.Range` etc.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop all worksheets
        Dim HeaderName As String
        HeaderName = Join(Array("ID", "GENDER", "REVENUE"))
        
        Dim HeaderRow As Range
        Set HeaderRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight))
    
        Dim Header As Variant
        For Each Header In HeaderRow
            Debug.Print Header
            Debug.Print HeaderName
            
            If InStr(1, HeaderName, Header.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, Header.Column), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Header.Column).End(xlUp)).Value2 = "Customer"
            End If
        Next Header
    Next ws

End Sub
```

---

Note that the `Range` object can take `Cells` as argument and does not need an `Address` therefore you can shorten this

```
Range(Cells(2, Header.Column).Address, Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, Header.Column).End(xlUp).Row, Header.Column).Address).Value2 = "Customer"
```

to

```
Range(Cells(2, Header.Column), Cells(Rows.Count, Header.Column).End(xlUp)).Value2 = "Customer"
```

---

**Thoughts according comments**

If your header changed that means `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Header.Column).End(xlUp)` ends up at the header because there is no data below. So this range

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, Header.Column), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Header.Column).End(xlUp)).Value2 = "Customer"
```

is actually going from row 2 to row 1. To prevent this, you need to split it up and test:

```
Dim LastCellInCol As Range
Set LastCellInCol = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Header.Column).End(xlUp)

If LastCellInCol.Row >= 2 Then 'only change if there is data in the column
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, Header.Column), LastCellInCol).Value2 = "Customer"
End If
```

---

If blanks should be filled until the very last row of all columns

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop all worksheets
        Dim HeaderName As String
        HeaderName = Join(Array("ID", "GENDER", "REVENUE"))
        
        Dim LastUsedCell As Range  'find last used cell of ALL columns
        Set LastUsedCell = Nothing 'initialize (because inside loop)
        Set LastUsedCell = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        
        If Not LastUsedCell Is Nothing Then 'prevent error on empty sheets
            Dim HeaderRow As Range
            Set HeaderRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, ws.Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        
            Dim Header As Variant
            For Each Header In HeaderRow
                If InStr(1, HeaderName, Header.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, Header.Column), ws.Cells(LastUsedCell.Row, Header.Column)).Value2 = "Customer"
                End If
            Next Header
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Any tips for lack of consistency? Few variables seem to have changed header because of macro, or they don't really have all cells filled with Customer (they're blank) for no reason

Comment: @rainbowthug for changed headers see my edited answer. I cannot reproduce inconsistencies. Note that `Set HeaderRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight))` will not find the very last header if there are blanks in the header you must use `Set HeaderRow = ws.Cells(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))`. Can you give a small example that produces the mentioned blanks?

Comment: i've updated initial question, thanks for your help

Comment: See my edited answer. You need to find the very last cell of **all** columns not the last cell of each individual column to fill them all until the end. I still cannot reproduce any header issues when using the code of my answer.

Comment: Not just a *jot down* answer, but  thorough & helpful explanations +:)

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work out perfectly. 
Does the part Set LastUsedCell = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious) just search for anything, presented as an asterisk? 

You are great man, thank you for your help!

Comment: @rainbowthug `UsedRange` is the range of cells that is used. `Find("*"` then will just search for any content in that range `xlByRows` row wise (you want to find a row) and `xlPrevious` backwards (you want to find the last row that has any data).